# What's the difference between these topological spaces on a square? (Why aren't they homotopic)?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Taking a square, $I = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and points $a = (0.5,0.5), b = (0.5,0), c = (0,0)$:

1. Is $X \setminus \{a\} \simeq X \setminus \{b\}$?
2. Is $X \setminus \{a\} \simeq X \setminus \{c\}$?
3. Is $X \setminus \{b\} \simeq X \setminus \{c\}$?

For 1. It seems to me like no, because their fundamental groups are $\mathbb{Z}$ and trivial respectively. As for the others, to me it seems like there is no difference between  $X \setminus \{a\} $ and $ X \setminus \{c\}$. Am I wrong? How is this assumption proven (if I'm correct)?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: *Maps* can be (or not be) *homotopic*, whereas *spaces* can be (or not be) *homotopy equivalent*.

Comment: Also, did you mean to say that it seems like there's no difference between $X\setminus\{b\}$ and $X\setminus\{c\}$?

Comment: Yes, Zev, whats the difference?

Comment: @JohnH.: Your objection to (1) also works for (2). The two spaces in (3) are homeomorphic.

Comment: Thanks Mike. How do I prove it?

Comment: @John: Use radial contraction towards the centre at $\langle 0.5,0.5\rangle$ to shrink the spaces in (3) to disks, each of which is missing one point on its boundary; then rotate one to align it with the other.